# Cant get numbers to fill in Tic Tac Toe example

Tags: reactjs

So I am really new to ReactJS and been a while since I learned JS.   I am using Sublime 3 Editor, and set the syntax to Babel (javascript).   I can get the first board to show without numbers through  npm run build.  I then edit the two pieces of code it asks for,

```
    class Board extends React.Component {
     renderSquare(i) {
       return <Square value={i} />;
     }
   }
   Change Square’s render method to show that value by replacing {/* TODO */} with {this.props.value}:

   class Square extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <button className="square">
            {this.props.value}
          </button>
        );
      }
    }
```

...  The problem is I still get the blank board.  It is supposed to show up with the square numbers instead.

This is My code...

```
    class Square extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <button className="square">
            {this.props.value}
          </button>
        );
      }
    }

    class Board extends React.Component {
      renderSquare(i) {
        return <Square value={i} />;
      }


      render() {
        const status = 'Next player: X';

        return (
          <div>
            <div className="status">{status}</div>
             <div className="board-row">
              {this.renderSquare(0)}
              {this.renderSquare(1)}
              {this.renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
              {this.renderSquare(3)}
              {this.renderSquare(4)}
              {this.renderSquare(5)}
             </div>
             <div className="board-row">
              {this.renderSquare(6)}
              {this.renderSquare(7)}
              {this.renderSquare(8)}
             </div>
          </div>
         );
       }
     }

    class Game extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="game">
            <div className="game-board">
              <Board />
             </div>
             <div className="game-info">
               <div>{/* status */}</div>
               <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
             </div>
           </div>
         );
       }
     }

     // ========================================

     ReactDOM.render(
       <Game />,
       document.getElementById('root')
     );
```

I checked the code and it appears to read the same to me... anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The only thing I notice is that the color code is off on the `React.Component` part...

```js
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }


  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine when I placed it in the snippet, the only thing is I enabled Babel to transform for supporting JSX. You can check the logs to spot the error.

You can also use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) to get have automatically setup proper tooling for you.

```js
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }


  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Ok,  TY for the help... I run the  create-react-app ...  it created everything,  and then I run npm start .. it starts and only shows the blank start box.  But then I looked in sublime 3 more and found this ...  under tools.. babel - babel transform..  when I run that .. I get this... 

Error: C:\Users\awilh\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Babel\babel-transform.js:33

      throw new Error('Couldn\'t find babel or babel-core');

      ^



Error: Couldn't find babel or babel-core

  ?

Comment: the code snippet you changed works.. it must be my setup somehow on my local system...

Comment: using create-react-app you will create separate project and can place the above code within `App.jsx`

Comment: Ok,  I tried that and it looks for the index.js file. If I leave the index.js file in there, I get the same result.

Comment: `RenderDOM` is in `index.js` and `App.js` needs to export the components

Comment: ok,  so I commented out the dom component out of the jsx, and ran this command -  npm start app.jsx   but the square still comes up blank.

Comment: You can check the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-dew-ggz5e